# Changing language of output

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp, date-format

I have this code to show some records out of my database. Now I have this timestamp and I am doing a `Date_format` on that records but this will display me the month ect in english and I would love to change it to an other languagefor example Dutch. How do I do that? So it wil display it in the correct language

[How it is in the Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NmaT.png)

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(create_time, '%d %M %Y') AS datum, reacties.*,
       klanten.foto, klanten.voornaam, klanten.achternaam
FROM reacties 
    LEFT JOIN klanten ON klanten.id = reacties.klant_id
    LEFT JOIN topics ON topics.id = reacties.topic_id
ORDER BY punten DESC
```

Comment: try this way `FORMAT(create_time, 'dd/MM/yyyy', 'en-US' ) `

Comment: @Bhargav I want it to change to Dutch?

Comment: Use ISO standard formats (YYYY-MM-DD) and don't worry about month names.

Comment: will it say the June as we say in the Netherlands Juni? is what it does?